# SQL string to replace content between 2 words

Tags: mysql, replace, between

I have searched for this and many others talk about replace command but I don`t wanna do a misstake with that.

My case is: I have a Wordpress blog and a script insert content in the posts. Now I wanna delete this new content but to keep the old one.

Its something like "This is content of a post about me" its the old content, and now the script insert another line, and the value of the field looks like `"This is content of a post about me <div class="spnsor"><a [...]</div>".`

In this part I have a different link from a post to post. But is the same construction with the same div and class.

I have over 2000 posts so is to much to edit every post.

How can I fix this from Mysql?

Its ok this command?
`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '<div class="spnsor">*</div>', '' )`

Comment: there was a div tag looks like >div< class="sponsor"<*>/div<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the MySQL server, you can look here : [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

If not, the easiest way is to do the replacement in a php script.

EDIT:

a simple php script. I have not tested it, but it should work (try before on a local backup)

```
<?php

    $co = mysql_connect("your server", "your login", "your password");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    mysql_select_db("database name", $co);

    $selectQuery = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM wp_posts";

    $res = mysql_query($selectQuery, $co) or exit(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '" . addslashes(preg_replace("/<div class=\"sponsor\">(.*)<\/div>/", '', $row['post_content'])) . "' WHERE ID = " . $row['ID'];
        mysql_query($updateQuery) or exit(mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($co);

?>
```

Comment: I have access but I`m dump! I need the exactly command to run!

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 're sleeping alone. No house no where to call a home. Tell me what I'm meant to s' at line 1

Comment: Try with `addslashes(preg_replace("/<div class=\"sponsor\">(.*)<\/div>/", '', $row['post_content']))`

Comment: Now it was ok, the link is gone but this change the post content. I use UTF8 for text, I`m romanian and my language has some characters different than english .... they disappeared and instead i have "?"

Comment: OK, after mysql_select_db, add : `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` and `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`. I have update the initial script ;)

Comment: The same effect ... I use this ... `mysql_select_db("jorjetta_blog", $co);
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");`

Comment: mysql_set_charset('utf8'); this is the solution! I put it before mysql_select_db